# Moment of memory allocation of class?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management

Form the link below [Difference between Definition and Declaration](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration/) says that:

> Definition of a variable says where the variable gets stored. i.e.,
> memory for the variable is allocated during the definition of the
> variable.

And to my knowledge, the declaration of class looks like :

```
class stu ;
```

And the definition of class looks like :

```
class stu{
   public:
        int x; 
};
```

And so from information above , the memory allocation of this class should happen when I write the complete definition of class.However,
from [this link](https://coderedirect.com/questions/587086/memory-allocation-for-regular-class-static-class-static-method-instanve-method-a) says that :

> Memory will be allocated when you create an instance of the class.

which means that the memory woudl be allocated at the moment I write

`stu s;`

So I would like to know the exact time that memory would allocate for thsi class, in the other word, it happens during compile time or run time?

Comment: Your citation says "Definition of a **variable** [...]". A class definition by itself isn't a variable definition.

Comment: Definition of a **variable** and definition of a **class** are two completely different things

Comment: Just for clarity, neither declaring nor defining a class takes any memory (except in the compiler, at compile time). But now we're talking about the compiler implementation, and not about your program.

Comment: @Mat , oh I am not aware of this, can you tell me more about the difference between "Definition of a variable" and "Definition of a class" or any reference that have detail of this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In general: The memory holding the values for the members is allocated when they are used, which is - with some exceptions - at runtime. (assuming it is not optimized away by the compiler)

The forward declaration of a class is for the compiler to make the type known.

The definition describes the class:

- its member functions are transformed into machine code. Those - depending on the target architecture - exist in a data section that is loaded into memory. So the member function takes up memory before any instance is created.
- The compiler also stores some information about the memory layout, which is either part of the machine code or also exists somewhere in a data section.

This memory allocation is however about the description of the class, and not what is generally referred to when you talk about memory allocation for a type.

The memory holding the values for the members is allocated when they are used which is generally at runtime. Under certain circumstances, the values of an instance of a type can already be determined at compile-time, which might have the result that those also become part of the data section.

Comment: Thanks for you clear answer.To sum up your answer , there's no memory allocation happens during compile time for class ? But this concept does not hold for variable like int,float ...etc  ?

Comment: To be a bit moer clear, there's no memory allocation even the compiler read the code of class definition during compile time, compiler only cares  about  memory layout of class( the size of data members and  other varaiables in member function  ), the actual memory  allocation happens at run time (create the instance of class) ?